# Neo4j cannot start: Java Heap Space error

Tags: java, neo4j

I am have been using neo4j-community-2.0.0-M04 and all of a sudden the neo4j database has started giving

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Here is the log extract from neo4j server logs: http://pastebin.com/Lr0guH1F

Neo4j system startup command is shown below:

> Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
>   -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xms1200m -Xmx1512m

The Server has 1.7GB memory. I have tried reducing the memory from 1200MB to 512MB but that doesn't work either. 
Not sure what can be done.

Comment: try -Xms64m (minimum for JVM)

Comment: doesnt work, I had to gibe the -Xms value to 2400MB to get it started and upgrade the server to 3.5 GB :(